# MSBuild and BuildUri

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to add a BuildStep to the AfterBuild target in MSBuild and I am using the following

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">    
    <ItemGroup>      
        <TestAssemblies Include="$(OutDir)\DataStoreUnitTests.dll" />   
    </ItemGroup>    

    <BuildStep      
        Name="Run unit Tests"
        TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"     
        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"      
        Message="Running unit tests">      
        <Output TaskParameter="Id" PropertyName="StepId" />    
    </BuildStep>    

    <Gallio      
        Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)"      
        ReportTypes="html"      
        ReportFileNameFormat="buildreport{0}{1}"      
        ReportOutputDirectory="." />    

    <BuildStep      
        TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"      
        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"      
        Id="$(StepId)"      
        Message="Yay! All tests succeded!"      
        Status="Succeeded" />    
        <OnError ExecuteTargets="MarkBuildStepAsFailed" />  
    </Target>  

    <Target Name="MarkBuildStepAsFailed">    
        <BuildStep      
            TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"      
            BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"      
            Id="$(StepId)"      
            Message="Tests have failed. See test report in drop folder for details." 
            Status="Failed" />  
</Target>
```

And when I run it in MSBuild I get the following error:

> error MSB4044: The "BuildStep" task was not given a value for the required 
>   parameter "BuildUri".

And I cannot see why, does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running this target as part of a Team Build (on the build server) or as a Desktop build (i.e. locally)?

The BuildUri property is normally populated passed in to the build by the build agent when it is triggering a new team build.  In your script the Uri is used to tell TFS what build detail to attach the build step to.  If you are running a desktop build then this will be empty unless you pass the property in on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

My thoughts are that `$(BuildUri)` is evaluating to nothing.  Try doing a print statement to debug and target the line number that VS/MSBuild is giving as an error.

```
<Message Text="$(BuildUri)" />
```

MSBuild can be run from the command line (I find MSBuild to be easier to work with that way) with the following command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%FrameWork_Version%\MSBuild /verbosity:n
%Solution or Project file%
```

To set `$(BuildUri)`:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BuildUri>Build_Uri_Value</BuildUri >
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        ...
```

Information on BuildUri can be found here:

> [What is the BuildUri and where do i get it from when i'm just trying to get some source?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/45c1709f-c0c4-4d95-b84b-a081113de586/)